# How do I define myself how functions must use my objects when making them available to theses functions (using my object at the end of the spec)?

Tags: oracle, plsql

In this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72870721/how-to-find-the-list-of-the-oracle-intefaces),  I've given examples of package/object that :

- implement some functions.
- are used to define other functions by only making them availaible to those functions. It means. I don't write a function body but only a spec with "using package_name" or "using package_body" in the end.

I suppose that the way to use my pakcage/object to implement another function is defined somewhere.

I would like to know if there  a way to define myself how to use a package/object. I want  a way to implement a functions without writing the body everytime but only by writing in the spec that the function is using my package.

What I'm asking for is similar to already implemented function in a interface in java or an extention method in c#.

P.S. : I don't think that title is very clear. I would be glad if someone would propose another title.

Answer (score 1):

> I want a way to implement a functions without writing the body everytime but only by writing in the spec that the function is using my package.

You cannot define a function/procedure that references an SQL stored function/procedure like that. If you declare a function or procedure then it must include the signature and the body.

From [the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/pls/topic/lookup?ctx=en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/sqlrf&id=LNPLS2178):

> #### `create_function::=`
>
> [image: Create function syntax diagram]
>
> #### `plsql_function_source ::=`
>
> [image: PL/SQL function source syntax]

For a standalone function the `body` is required.

For a call specification, you can reference a function but it will be an external Java method or a C function and **NOT** another function defined in SQL.